# Is there an adjective for the subsets of the integers where the sum of reciprocals of numbers in the subset diverges?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, terminology

I'd like to know if there is an adjective for subsets $S$ of the positive integers such that

$$\sum_{n \in S} \frac{1}{n} = \infty$$

Comment: Cf. [large set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_set_(combinatorics)).  (The set of prime numbers is an example)

Comment: Positive natural density ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density

Comment: See also the [Müntz–Szász theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Müntz-Szász_theorem) for an interesting application.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit No, positive natural density is a significantly stronger property (e.g. primes do not have positive density), so this term is unusable for the desired purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A set of positive integers such that the sum of the reciprocals diverges is called a [large set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_set_(combinatorics)).

For example, the set of prime numbers is large.